# what does id field means? (nf_conntrack struct member)

Tags: netfilter

I am studying linux conntrack(command line interface for netfilter connection tracking).

And I have a question. `what is id field which is nf_conntrack struct member?`

what is that id?

Message id? or Kernel Session Table Entry id?

If both are incorrect, then what is id?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Each unique TCP connection or UDP session (defined by source/dest & ip/port) gets assigned one unique ID.

> conntrack --dump conntrack --output extended,id

However as soon as it closed or expires the ID number can be reused. I have seen repeating IDs as close as one minute, so generally speaking the ID is **not** a good way to identify connections along time.